# Unable to read MP3 file in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, mp3

```
library(tuneR)
Awaaz <- readWave("C:/Users/Ram/Downloads/XC312210 - Mallee Emu-wren - Stipiturus mallee.mp3" , 
                   from = 1, to = Inf,"samples", header = FALSE, toWaveMC = NULL)
```

Getting below error message...

> Error in while (!(RIFF == "RIFF" && WAVE == "WAVE")) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Please read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks . Not so much work for you but will make it much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TuneR
>
> - **readWave**: reading Wave files
> - **readMP3**: read an MPEG-2 layer 3 file into a Wave object

`readWave` reads Wave files, and `readMP3` reads MP3 files. Simple enough.